# How to get Duplicate records from single table depends on column value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I got table like this:

```
declare @t1 table(Pat_Ref int,Fname VARCHAR(20), Sname VARCHAR(20),minor VARCHAR(1),SourceSys VARCHAR(40),regdt datetime)

insert into @t1 
values   (111,'John', 'Wayne','N','ick','2015-06-09 21:31:09.253')
        ,(111,'John', 'Wayne','N','ick','2014-05-09 21:31:09.253')
        ,(111,'John', 'Wayne',null,'hpk','2015-04-09 21:31:09.253')

        ,(112,'Jill', 'Smith','N','ick','2015-01-08 21:31:09.253')
        ,(112,'Jill', 'Smith',null,'hpk','2015-05-01 21:31:09.253')

        ,(113,'Bill', 'Peyton','N','ick','2015-06-09 21:31:09.253')

        ,(114,'Gill', 'Peyton','N','hpk','2015-06-09 21:31:09.253')
        ,(114,'Gill', 'Peyton','N','hpk','2015-06-12 21:31:09.253')
        ,(114,'Gill', 'Peyton','N','ick','2006-10-22 21:31:09.253')

        ,(115,'Billy', 'Peyton','N','hpk','2015-06-09 21:31:09.253')

        ,(116,'William', 'nixon','N','ick','2015-06-09 21:31:09.253')
        ,(116,'William', 'nixon','N','ick','2015-06-09 21:31:09.253')
```

I want duplicate records based on `Pat_Ref` and values between `ick` and `hpk` on `SourceSys` column. If duplicate record found row must be recent date `regdt`

`Note:` From the above table `Pat_Ref=116`, there are two rows but it can't be duplicate because its `SourceSys` value is same `ick`. if that value is `ick` on row and `hpk` on another row then it can become duplicate row.

I want result like this;

```
Pat_Ref     Fname   Sname   minor   SourceSys   regdt
111         John    Wayne   N       ick         2015-06-09 21:31:09.253
112         Jill    Smith   NULL    hpk         2015-05-01 21:31:09.253
114         Gill    Peyton  N       hpk         2015-06-12 21:31:09.253
```

Any help. Thanks

Comment: Why is William nixon not in the result?

Comment: @SeanLange I think because it must contain both `ick` and `hck`.

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas, yes you are right values must contain ick and hck. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you right, that's the query I came up with and and it does seem to return expected results:

```
SELECT Pat_Ref, Fname, Sname, minor, SourceSys, regdt
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pat_ReF ORDER BY regdt DESC) AS RN, *
    FROM @t1
) AS T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 1
    FROM @t1 AS T2
    WHERE T2.Pat_Ref = T.Pat_Ref
        AND T2.SourceSys BETWEEN 'hck' AND 'ick'
    GROUP BY T2.Pat_Ref
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T2.SourceSys) > 1
    ) AS T2(UQ)
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```

**Explanation:**
I'm using `ROW_NUMBER()` to get most recent `regdt` for each `Pat_Ref` in case it needs to be filtered.

And I'm using `CROSS APPLY` to get DISTINCT `COUNT()` for each `Pat_Ref` `SourceSys` and if I understood it right, it must match both ICK and HCK.

Any questions - let me know.

Comment: Hi @Evaldas Buinauskas, thanks for the reply. it is working fine. I will apply this logic in my main cod. thanks again

Comment: I just tested on my database. Its working fine.If I get any problem I will let you know.  Thanks again.